# Expected Number of Tests to Find Defective Parts

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Not doing this for homework, but for interview prep. The problem is this:

> A bin of 5 electrical components is known to contain 2 that are
>   defective. If the components are to be tested one at a time, in random
>   order, until the defectives are discovered, find the expected number
>   of tests that are made.

My attempt at the solution is this:

$E[X = tests] = 2(\frac{1}{5*4}) + 3(2!*\frac{3}{5*4*3}) + 4(\frac{3!}{2!1!}*\frac{3*2}{5*4*3*2}) + 5(\frac{4!}{3!1!}*\frac{3*2*1}{5*4*3*2*1}) = 2$

Although I don't actually know the correct solution to this problem, 2 seems like it would not intuitively be correct for the problem.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong or how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not right. Note for example that $5$ tests are never needed.

Answer (score 3):

Since the tests are conducted sequentially, there are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ distinct ways in which the two defective components can appear in the testing sequence order:  $$\begin{align*} (D,D,G,G,G) \\ (D,G,D,G,G) \\ (D,G,G,D,G) \\ (D,G,G,G,D) \\ (G,D,D,G,G) \\ (G,D,G,D,G) \\ (G,D,G,G,D) \\ (G,G,D,D,G) \\ (G,G,D,G,D) \\ (G,G,G,D,D) \end{align*}$$  Each of these is equally likely.  Now, for each enumerated ordering, what is the number of components tested until the **second** occurrence of $D$ is encountered?  For the first outcome, this happens on the second test, for example.

For those outcomes where the second defective item is last in the testing sequence, you would note that by the fourth test it has not yet been found, yet the final test is not needed since you know that it must be defective.  Moreover, for the final case where three items were tested and were all good, you could also stop there because the last two tests are guaranteed to be on the defective items.

Comment: Cool. That makes a lot of sense! So the correct answer would be $E[X] = 2(1/10) + 3(3/10) + 4(6/10) = 3.5$ ?

Comment: I had missed the final paragraph. Good analysis.